# expected expression on else if condition

Tags: ios, if-statement

I have the following code to determine if the game should move to the next level. The last else if and else condition cause and two errors. "expected expression" and "expected identifier. If I comment those conditions out the code compiles just fine. Not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        SKNode *n = [self nodeAtPoint: [touch locationInNode:self]];
        if (n !=self && [n.name isEqual:@"restartLabel"] && _gameLevel == 0){
            [[self childNodeWithName:@"restartLabel"] removeFromParent];
            [[self childNodeWithName:@"winLoseLabel"] removeFromParent];
            SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
            SKScene * myScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
            [self.view presentScene:myScene transition: reveal];
            return;
        }
    else if (n !=self && [n.name isEqual:@"nextLevelLabel"] && _gameLevel == 1)
        {
            [[self childNodeWithName:@"nextLevelLabel"] removeFromParent];
            [[self childNodeWithName:@"winLoseLabel"] removeFromParent];
            SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
            SKScene * myScene2 = [[MyScene2 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
            [self.view presentScene:myScene2 transition: reveal];
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (n !=self && [n.name isEqual:@"nextLevelLabel"] && _gameLevel == 2)
        {
            [[self childNodeWithName:@"nextLevelLabel"] removeFromParent];
            [[self childNodeWithName:@"winLoseLabel"] removeFromParent];
            SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
            SKScene * myScene3 = [[MyScene3 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
            [self.view presentScene:myScene3 transition: reveal];
            return;
        }
}
    else
        {            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"End of the Road" message:@"You reached the end of the game. More levels coming soon!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"  nil]
            [alert show];
        }
    @end
```

Comment: The 2nd `else if` is after the closing curly brace of the `for` loop.

Comment: And it looks like you might have an extra closing brace right before the `else`. You should remove both of these and add the loop's closing brace after the else.

Comment: You should be using `isEqualToString:` instead of `isEqual:` to do name comparison. This is because `NSString` literals in code are implements as singletons (all instances of identical string literals have the same address), and may have a different address than a string with the same characters that originated from some other source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
else if (n !=self && [n.name isEqual:@"nextLevelLabel"] && _gameLevel == 1)
    {
        [[self childNodeWithName:@"nextLevelLabel"] removeFromParent];
        [[self childNodeWithName:@"winLoseLabel"] removeFromParent];
        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
        SKScene * myScene2 = [[MyScene2 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:myScene2 transition: reveal];
        return;
    }
}   <--- remove this
```

Comment: Not so much wrong, as incomplete, but yeah, yours should've been accepted.

Answer (score 5):

The 2nd `else if` and the last `else` are after the closing curly brace of the `for` loop.

May I suggest you work on curly brace consistency and the following layout to avoid such a problem.

```
for (...) {
    if (...) {
    } else if (...) {
    } else if (...) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Doing it this way makes it readable and easy to spot mistakes.

You may prefer curly braces on their own lines and that is fine. Pick a style and use it every where. The code you posted is used two different styles. That just leads to problems.

Comment: Pro tip: select some code and hit Control-I in Xcode to auto-indent each line.